# How to manage pipelines in multiple branches, in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server

Let's say I have branch fetaure1, where there is pipeline file.

The trigger will be like this.

```
trigger:
   - feature1
```

For development purpose, I created a new branch from it say (feature1_deveoper1)

But, even though this new branch has this pipeline file, need to modify this again to get trigger working from it.

```
trigger:
   - feature1
   - feature1_developer1
```

So, after all my work, let's say I want to merge to the feature1 branch, again I need to remove this new feature entry and merge it to the branch.

Any better approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know everyone has different workflows, but in a more traditional git usage pattern, like say gitflow, you wouldn't setup CI builds on short feature branches.

Each dev would of course make a feature branch off of a branch like say **develop**.  They would work on the feature locally.  When they're done, they make a PR, and it gets merged back into your bigger branch -- say develop or release or main or whatever.

That way the triggers section only needs to have the names of the main (long-lived)  branches.